# play framework routing error

Tags: routes, playframework

Apparently I don't understand Play's routing as well as I thought.  I was trying to get the url for a form looking the way I want, and I'm getting `StackOverflowError` from `Groups.view`'s call to `render` caused by infinite recursion in `play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:62)`.

This was all working fine when I had the default catch-all route.  What I have now is:

```
GET  /groups/{<[\d\w]+=.*>rdn}      ldapauth.Groups.view
POST /groups/{<[\d\w]+=.*>rdn}  ldapauth.Groups.save
```

`Groups.view` works fine until I add a reference to `Groups.save`:

```
#{form @ldapauth.Groups.save(rdn: 'cn=test')}`
#{/form}
```

on the view page, then I get the error above.  Anybody know what the actual problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UnBind is the class that converts the parameters to the proper Java/Scala object.

I believe your error comes from adding *rdn: 'cn=test'* to the method. Define a hidden input with the name *rdn* and the value you want, and let Play do the unbinding.

I warn you this may not solve your issue though, there are many known issues related to the routing, Play doesn't behave nicely in some scenarios. I would recommend you to change the definition of post to something like:

```
POST /groups/save/{<[\d\w]+=.*>rdn}  ldapauth.Groups.save
```

and in the last line of save you call

```
view(<params>)
```

so you are redirected back to the get view (or another method if you want to go somewhere else).